# how to judge android phone is shutdown by adb tools?

Tags: android, adb

When I turn off my android phone, and then I run the "adb devices" command, it lists all connected devices.
When I did not turn off the phone and then ran the same command, it returned the same result as before.
So now I want to know if there is a way to determine whether the phone is turned off.

Answer (score 0):

`adb devices` shows the connection state of the device can be one of the following:

- offline: The device is not connected to adb or is not responding.
- device: The device is now connected to the adb server. Note that this state does not imply that the Android system is fully booted and operational because the device connects to adb while the system is still booting. However, after boot-up, this is the normal operational state of an device.
- no device: There is no device connected.